# Name of (open ?) set-theoretic conjecture

Tags: set-theory

Is there a common or 'educational' name for the following set-theoretic conjecture:

Let M be a model of ZF, which also has the following property:
image(m) <= domain(m), for any map m (1).
Then Zermelo's axiom of choice also holds in M.'

Hereinafter, I call the condition in line (1) 'small image principle'. This name is appropriate, since the condition is that there is an *injection* from the image of m into m's domain. In this sense, the image of m is small in comparison with m's domain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as "The Partition Principe", or rather the statement that the image of a set injects into the original set is known as the partition principle. The question whether or not it implies the axiom of choice has been asked explicitly since at least 1902, making it about 120 years old.

It has a very interesting history, on which I have written before. Last year a group from Brazil claimed to have shown that it does not imply the axiom of choice by developing a new framework called "Flow". I never got around to finish reading their paper properly (the first version was riddled with problem, I am talking about the revision, of course).

We do know, for example, that the partition principle implies the axiom of choice for well-ordered families of arbitrary sets, which in turn implies the Principle of Dependent Choice as well as the existence of sets of reals which are not Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Related: [MO on FLOW](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373700/is-the-theory-flow-actually-consistent).

Comment: (Although this pertains to the first version of the paper.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer which essentially is 'partition principle'. I always regarded this name to be quite a misnomer, but wanted to be sure. I'll stick to 'small image principle' because it is equivalent to 'The image of m is small in comparison to its domain, for any map m'. Of course, this view is map-centric and one could argue that the main topic is sets, not maps.

Comment: @Peterש: You might also consider "Hausdorff" as a misnomer, and want to call it "separable" because you "are able to separate points". But the names in the literature are there to let us have a joint language. Please take that into consideration, that whomever is going to read your work will not be able to easily communicate with others. Also, it is not a misnomer, since partitions are exactly generated by fibers of functions, so really it says that a partition of a set $S$ injects into $S$.

Comment: Actually, according to German mathematical language 'hausdorffsch' and 'seperabel' are synonyms. 
Also, what precisely do you mean by 'generated'.

Comment: @Peterש: If only English was German... As for the term generated, if $P$ is a partition of $S$ then there is a function $f\colon S\to X$, where $X$ is some set, such that $C\in P$ if and only if $C=f^{-1}(x)$ for some $x\in X$. And every function $f$ with domain $S$ induces a partition by considering the fibers.

Comment: @Peterש: Also, at least according to Wikipedia you may be confusing separabler and separierten.

Comment: Yes, one example of such a map f is f: S --> P, s -> s(P), where s(P) denotes *the* element of P containing s. 'And every function f with domain S induces a partition by considering the fibers.' Yes. But now, what precisely is the link to 'partition principle' as defined in your initial answer ?

Comment: @Peterש: The principle states that if we partition a set $S$, then the partition has size that is at most that of $S$ itself. As I wrote in a previous comment. The weak partition principle says that a partition of $S$ is *at least* not strictly larger than $S$ itself.

Comment: 'The principle states that if we partition a set S, then the partition has size that is at most that of S itself.' No. The 'partition principle', as given in your initial answer, may *imply* that, only. If the 'partition principle' is essentially about or specific to partition-theory, and not sets or maps in general, why isn't it stated that way ?

Comment: @Peterש: No. You are wrong. The partition principle was originally formulated as thus: If $P$ is a partition of $S$, then $|P|\leq|S|$.

Comment: @Peterש: If you can't see why, spend more time thinking about it. I've spent about a decade now thinking about this. As to PP being "about or specific to partition theory", it is a statement about the size of partitions, which you can also formulate in terms of image and domain of a function. Much like how you can say that Hahn–Banach is a statement about linear funcitonals on a Banach space, but you can also formulate it in terms of the existence of probability measures. Things, especially in the study of choice principles tend to have plenty of formulations, but are named after the original.

Comment: OK, this explains a lot, in particular the name 'partition principle' and why the name 'small image principle' may be rejected. I still wonder, however, why the 'partition principle' is often stated in disguise in terms of *arbitrary* sets A and B, instead of 'For any partition P, the size of P is at most the size of its union.'

Comment: @Asaf: I meant 'separiert', not 'separabel'.

Comment: @Peterש: So it turns out that Hausdorff and separable are not synonymous after all, huh... Who would have thought! :)

Comment: @Asaf: You seem to be in good mood, recently. Thus one more question: You say the small image principle is the partition principle in disguise, right ? So let m be map, mP the partition of domain(m) induced by m, ms the *surjection* from domain(m) onto mP induced by m, and mi the *injection* from mP onto image(m) induced by m. Then m = mi∘ms. More importantly, image(m) ~ mP via mi. Thus, you are right regarding the equivalence of the principles. But now my question: Doesn't the existence of mi requires the axiom of choice ?

Comment: @Peterש: No, because you defined mP using m, so if C is a cell in mP, then mi(C) = t if and only if m(x) = t for some/all x in C. (And since C is never empty, this has substance to it.)

Comment: We're not at the core of this matter, almost. I'm able to obtain the set(!) mP from m using, essentially, comprehension restricted to the power set of domain(m). Now that we have mP, how to define mi ? 'map' as I use it here is a Kuratowski map, i.e. a set of Kuratowski pairs. 'Kuratowski pair (a,b)' = {{a}, {a, b}}. (I'm aware that it's of ontological interest at most which set-theoretic implementation of the concept 'pair' you use, but let's stick to Kuratowski maps.) So we need to construct the set of all Kuratowski pairs (C, m(x)) , where  C element of mP, x element of C. How, precisely ?

Comment: We should *strictly* distinguish between background mathematics and its object, in this case sets. I admit I may have confused these worlds. Still, I see two things to consider here: (i) our background mathematics may include 'axiom of choice' (ii) all of the set-theoretic question sentences involving maps are strangely ambiguous, i.e. 'map' may mean either a tool of background mathematics or a set.

Comment: @Peterש: I've described the formula in my previous comment, which defines that bijection. $\{(C,m(x))\mid x\in C, C\in P\}$, and since $m$ is constant on each $C$, this is a well-defined function. We bound it in the obvious set, in case that's not clear.

Comment: @Asaf: Thank you for your reply.I reassured myself that the maps ms and mi exist in ZF, for any Kuratowski map m. For mi it goes as follows (RC meaning 'restricted comprehension'): For any sets A, B, A⨯B:={(a,b)={{a}, {b,a}}: a∈A, b∈B} exists. Why ? Apply RC to (A∪B) accordingly. Since mP and image(m) exist, so does mP⨯image(m). From the latter select mi by means of RC with the following criterion: select (a,b) iff ∃x ∈a:b=m(x). Thus, in a ZF-universe partition and small image principle are equivalent. What about our *background mathematics* ? There too, if it encompasses ZF.

Comment: BTW, I feel much like a bricklayer now. Axiomatic set theory can convey quite a handyman feeling.